# Third party apps doesn't show on slingshot

Tags: release-loki, thirdpartyapps, apps

I've installed some third party apps like google chrome, valentina server, xampp, etc. that is installed via gdebi package installer or eddy. Well, it is installed successfully however, it doesnt show in slingshot. Can you guys help me with it? Pleaseeeee. Thankssss

Answer (score 1):

I hate when my apps doesn't show up in the launcher too

I think AppEditor can solve your problems, it's a great app for editing our launcher/slingshot entries. Link: [AppEditor](http://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.appeditor/)

I will try to show you a practical example, hope it can help.

Goal: Create an icon to launch the Python Interpreter. As you can see I have no Python Interpreter in my Programming Section.
[image]

**Step 1.** Launch AppEditor.
[image]

As we can see there's no Python in Programming here as well:
[image]

**Step 2.** Activate -> **Show hidden entries**
[image]
Wow! Look who's here. Python it self! I will activate the 3.5

**Step 3.** Activate -> **Show in Launcher**. *Don't forget to Save*

[image]

Now let's check if it works.
[image]

That's it! You can play and change the categories and even edit the myapp.desktop file directly. In most cases this will work, of course we'll find some exceptions.

**Manual alternative**

Somtimes the .desktop file exists already but there's something wrong in the configs, check if they already exist in your .desktop files directory with the command: `ls ~/.local/share/applications` Check if there's a myapp.desktop already.

if not, you can create it yourself following the next steps.

Create a .desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications/myapp.desktop` (you can use AppEditor to create a new one and it will give the same result)

Manual Ex: `touch ~/.local/share/applications/chrome-browser.desktop`
this example command would create a chrome-browser.desktop or you can use any text editor and just save there.

The contents of the .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Encoding=UTF-8  
Type=Application  
Name=Python(v3.5) #Application name, Chrome for example
Comment=Python Interpreter #This will show up on mouse hover 
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/python3.5.xpm #icon full path or the application name ex. chrome  
Exec=/usr/bin/python3.5 #path to the program executable    
Categories=Development;  #the category it will show up
Terminal=false  
StartupNotify=true
```

**Example2**. My manually crated netbeans.desktop launcher, in `~/.local/share/applications/netbeans.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Encoding=UTF-8  
Type=Application  
Name=Netbeans  
Icon=/home/felipe/Downloads/apps/netbeans/nb/netbeans.png  
Exec=/home/felipe/Downloads/apps/netbeans/bin/netbeans  
Comment=Netbeans IDE  
Categories=Development;  
Terminal=false  
StartupNotify=true
```

The executable is located in my `Downloads/apps/netsbeans/bin` directory

Comment: Chrome, Valentina Studio, etc. still doesn't exist, it doesn't show in AppEditor too. Help please

Comment: Hi, I'd update the answer for creating it manually. You'll need to know where the app installed are located.

When I don't know where something is installed I use the command find.
ex. ```sudo find / -name "chrome"``` and it will look for everything with chrome than you can point the executable in the .desktop file.

Comment: The funny thing is that Eddy always creates the application launcher for me, never used Gdebi tough.